# Finding the two diagonals intersecting at a given point in 2D Matrix

Tags: java, arrays

I am pretty new to programming and I ran into a problem doing my java homework assignment.

Quick definitions for this post:

- Position = (row index, column index)
- The diagonals I am talking about are the ones intersecting at the given position.
- The diagonals always start from an edge of the matrix.
- diagonal 1 runs from top left to bottom right
- diagonal 2 runs from bottom left to top right
- the 'length' of a diagonal is the number of entries on that diagonal

I was given a 8x8 Matrix full of chars, a specific position in the matrix and was trying to find out three things:

1. Given a certain position in the matrix, at what position does the
   diagonal running from the top left corner towards the right bottom
   corner start?
2. Same question for the diagonal running from bottom left corner
   towards top right corner.
3. What is the length of each?

I could not find anything about this question so I came up with these solutions I will give in Pseudo-Code:

Assuming the indices go from 0 to 7 like this:

```
  0 1 2 3 ... 7
0  
1
2
3
.
.
7    ...    .
```

If you are given a position X(n, m), to get the starting position for diagonal 1 you could to this:

```
while(n>0 && m>0){
    n--;
    m--;
}
diagonal1.startingPosition = (n, m);
```

For diagonal 2 this:

```
while(n<7 && m>0){
n++;
m--;
}
diagonal2.startingPosition = (n, m);
```

After calculating the starting positions, the length of those diagonals should be:

```
//the (n, m) used here are the values after the specific while loops,
//not the original (n, m). So for diagonal1, at least one of them == 0
//and for diagonal2, either n == 7 or m == 0.
diagonal1.length == (8 - max(n, m));
diagonal2.length == (8 - min(n, m));
```

I think this method should work for any square matrix.

Now, is there some formula I don't know to find all of this information? 
Is there a much simpler solution? 
Am I missing some fundamental (mathematical?) concepts here?

Thank you for your time

EDIT (some of the actual code used):

```
/*
Finding the diagonal from top left to bottom right
NOTE: in this case, diagonalStartingRow = n, and diagonalStartingColumn = m.
this way I do not actually change the original position (n,m), but I get the correct 
starting position to calculate the length of the diagonal, which I use in the for loop below the while loop
*/
while(diagonalStartingRow > 0 && diagonalStartingColumn > 0){
        diagonalStartingRow--;
        diagonalStartingColumn--;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 8 - Math.max(diagonalStartingRow,diagonalStartingColumn); i++) {
//the chessBoard is the 2D char array and the diagonalString1 will hold the String of the diagonal
        diagonalString1 += chessBoard[diagonalStartingRow+i][diagonalStartingColumn+i];
    }
```

Comment: At a glance, yes there is a basic algebraic formula which will give you what you want. Your formulas for the lengths are wrong.. did you not test them? diagonal1.length(0,0) != diagonal1.length(5,5), but it should be. A general tip if you can't figure out the formula immediately: manually calculate what you are looking for for a few example values and then look for the pattern.

Comment: Well the starting positions with given positions (0,0) and (5,5) will both be (0,0) and therefore the length will be 8 in both cases. Maybe I should have specified more, the diagonals always start from an edge of the matrix. The starting positions for a diagonal will always have either at least one 0 or at least one 7 in it, so it should work in any case. I tested the formula manually for several values, it always worked.

Comment: diagonal1.length(5, 5) == (8 - max(5, 5)) == (8 - 5) == 3 != 8 ?!

Comment: Sorry, I really shouldn't have used the same variables for everything! I will edit my post with the actual code I used. The thing is, you would not calculate the length with the (5,5). You would use the updated values you got after the while loop which calculates the starting position for diagonal1. So if you've got the position (5,5), to find the length of the diagonal going through that position, you do this: while(n > 0 && m > 0){n--; m--} and only after this while loop, you can calculate the length with the updated values, which would then be: diagonal1.length(0,0) == (8 - max(0,0)) == 8.